# echo shows command I want to execute

Tags: echo

First let me explain that I have very little expertise with bash scripting.  I only use it for very simple applications.

My script is used to generate a grep command.

I use the echo command as an interim debug tool.  I figure that if I can get the echo command to show the command I want to execute, all I have to do is remove the echo and the quotes and the command inside the echo should do what I want.

Here is my script (called grepper3.sh). Again, I am not an expert at this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what should I grep?"
read this

echo "grep -Ri \"$this\" > \"$this\""
```

Here is what happens when I execute:

```
master@master-Latitude-E6440:~$ ./grepper3.sh
what should I grep?
all that
grep -Ri "all that" > "all that"
```

The grep command being echoed by the code is exactly what I want.  But when I remove the echo and the surrounding double quotes:

```
was:         echo "grep -Ri \"$this\" > \"$this\""
changed to:  grep -Ri \"$this\" > \"$this\"
```

I get this:

```
master@master-Latitude-E6440:~$ ./grepper3.sh
what should I grep?
all that
./grepper3.sh: line 5: \"$this\": ambiguous redirect
```

I'm guessing that there is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add . to recursive search.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what should I grep?"
read this

grep -Ri $this > $this .
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to to is to change the quotation marks to backticks.

Your new code would be:

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "what should I grep?"
    read this

    echo `grep -Ri \"$this\" > \"$this\"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally got to work.  Thanks for all of your help!

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "what should I grep?"
    read this

    DEST="/home/master/results/$this"

    grep -Ri "$this" > "$DEST"
```